# Get azure container blobs list by directory

Tags: javascript, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I'm organizing my container content by directories

```
rep1/subrep1/subsubrep1'
rep2/subrep2/subsubrep2'
```

inside each rep I have blob files.

I would like to retrieve blobs list of `rep1/subrep1/subsubrep1'

the container called `tenants`.

```
try {
    const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
        process.env.AzureWebJobsStorage
    );

    const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
        'tenants'
    );
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
        let blobClient = await containerClient.getBlobClient(blob.name);
        let splitedString = blobClient.name.split('/')
        filesList.push({
            label: splitedString[splitedString.length].split(".wav")[0],
            value: blobClient.url
        });
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Actually with my code I should iterate all blob files.

I can filter then the result but I would find how to get a specific subfolder blobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `listBlobsFlat`, use [`listBlobsByHierachy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerclient?view=azure-node-latest#listblobsbyhierarchy-string--containerlistblobsoptions-). For `delimiter` parameter, specify an empty string and specify `rep1/subrep1/subsubrep1` as `prefix` in options parameter.

Something like:

```
let iter = await containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("", { prefix: "rep1/subrep1/subsubrep1/" });
```

Comment: I'm getting this access auth error when I use this method `The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'btOFCQtx3dyes5TzPbpMZxxxxxxxxx' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET`

Comment: My bad, I have made a small mistake. I forgot `/` at the end of the string and added `"/"` instead of `''` as first argument . Now it's working thanks.